# Heroku doesn't recognized installed packages

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app to Heroku, but, though successfully deployed, my Heroku app encounters the following error that makes it fail to run:

[image: screenshot of runtime logs]

Even though I have already installed the package with `pip install flask_sqlalchemy`.

My `app.py` is like the following:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, url_for
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

import pickle
with open('models/deploy_model.sav', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

db_name = 'schema.sql'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + db_name

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Mood(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'result'
    index = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    results = db.Column(db.Float)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    table = Mood.query.with_entities(Mood.results).all()
    table = [r for r, in table]
    return render_template('main.html', results =table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and my `requirements.txt` file currently also contains these packages:

```
...
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
...
```

Why can't Heroku find `flask_sqlalchemy`? How can I fix it?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

> Even though I have already installed the package with `pip install flask_sqlalchemy`

It's not clear whether you ran this on your development machine or on your Heroku dyno, but in either case it won't have any effect on your application running on Heroku.

If you ran it locally, this will have installed `flask_sqlalchemy` to your *local* environment. Heroku has no way to know what you have installed locally; it installs dependencies from your committed `requirements.txt` file or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, depending on the tools you have used.

If you ran it on Heroku, this will have run in a one-off dyno that was discarded as soon as you stopped interacting with it. All run-time dependencies *must* be declared in your requirements file so Heroku can include them in your application's slug.

Which leads us to your next statement:

> and my `requirements.txt` file currently also contains these packages:
>
> ```
> ...
> Flask==2.0.1
> Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
> ...
> ```

Is this file in the root of your repository? It must be, or else Heroku will ignore it.

Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`? Heroku will use Pipenv to install dependencies from *those* files if they are present. It will only use pip to install packages from the `requirements.txt` file if it cannot find Pipenv files. Pick one or the other.

If neither of these suggestions helps, please edit your question and show your build log.